# What's the meaning of the expression "flow of bloodlines, and yours is far too thin"?

Tags: meaning

A man is talking to a woman.

> We choose who we mate with. We decide the flow of bloodlines, and
>   yours is far too thin.

I am not sure about the meaning of *flow of bloodlines*. When someone says that a person has a *thin bloodline*, what does he mean?

Is it common to say that someone has a thin bloodline?

Comment: It means that he is an pretentious snob, and thinks that the upper classes are genetically superior to everybody else. "Far too thin" means she doesn't have enough upper-class ancestors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Bloodline* is another way of saying *descendants*. The flow of a bloodline is how the blood of one generation flows into the next. It is a metaphorical use.

The man is saying that they get to decide who has descendants. Saying that the woman's bloodline is "far too thin" is essentially saying she is not a good choice to mate with. Her bloodline does not flow well, because it is thin, so she will not have many, or any descendants.

Comment: The man is saying it to the woman, as in the OP's question.

Comment: ha! oops, misread that. I've updated the answer